# How do you connect WSO2 IS to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, wso2-identity-server

Following the instructions from WSO2 IS on setting it up with Microsoft SQL Server (https://docs.wso2.com/display/ML111/Setting+up+Microsoft+SQL), I continue to get the following error when running WSO2 IS:

> ERROR (com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection) - Java
>   Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.7 is not supported by this driver.
>   Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which provides support for JDBC
>   4.0.
>  ERROR (org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil) - Database Error - Java Runtime Environment (JRE) version 1.7 is not
>   supported by this driver. Use the sqljdbc4.jar class library, which
>   provides support for JDBC 4.0.

I made sure that there were no extra sqljdbc libraries in the paths (to rule out ambiguity). I followed the instructions exactly, but did note that they referenced SQL Server 2005 (yikes!).
I am working on a Windows 7 machine, JRE 8, JDK 1.7, SQL Server 2012/2014, and WSO2 IS 5.1.0.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using the JDK 1.7, so according to the [documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774) from microsoft you need to have Sqljdbc41.jar. Can you check you have the correct version in the lib folder?

> Sqljdbc41.jar requires a JRE of 7 and supports the JDBC 4.1 API

Also make sure that the dropins folder don't have any mssql libs before restarting the server (Jars from lib are copied to dropins at the startup, so there is a chance you have mssql jars copied from an earlier startup).

Also note that WSO2 IS has a [separate page](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Setting+up+Microsoft+SQL) for setting up databases. Please follow that doc instead which contains the documentation specific to IS.

Comment: You were correct. There were two issues:
1. I had to remove all sqljdbc#.jar files from the dropin folder.
2. I had to use the correct sqljdbc. For me, using Windows 7, JDK 1.7 and JRE 9 and SQL Server 2014 I had to use the sqljdbc version 6, and specifically the sqljdbc41.jar file. Thank you pulasthi7